# How to combine data from multiple rows into 1 row in oracle

Tags: oracle

Query:

```sql
SELECT 
   AC.TRN_REF_NO
  ,AC.EVENT
  ,AC.AC_NO
  ,AC.AC_CCY
  ,AC.FCY_AMOUNT
  ,AC.EXCH_RATE
  ,AC.LCY_AMOUNT
  ,AC.RELATED_CUSTOMER
  ,AC.TRN_CODE
FROM ACVW_ALL_AC_ENTRIES AC 
WHERE AC.TRN_REF_NO = '001INFT233140130';
```

combine 4 rows into 1 row with the sample data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: your expected results its like you want where rownum=1 , however your question is different the rest value of ac_no where did it go ? there is no summation in the results or concatenation

Comment: @Baalback, Regarding to value of ac_no, I have shared file please refer to the sample data with the query.

Comment: @DM19 You did not provide any details on how to determine `From_AC_NO`, `From_AC_CCY`, `To_AC_NO`and `To_AC_CCY`. In your sample data, what decides, that `001000004300032` is *From* and `001000004300010` is *To* ? What decides that `700008`and `8000008` do not show up at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to pivot the data:

```sql
SELECT TRN_REF_NO
     , EVENT
     , MAX(CASE WHEN fcy_amount IS NOT NULL THEN AC_NO  END) AS from_ac_no
     , MAX(CASE WHEN fcy_amount IS NOT NULL THEN AC_CCY END) AS from_ac_ccy
     , MAX(CASE WHEN fcy_amount IS NULL THEN AC_NO  END) AS to_ac_no
     , MAX(CASE WHEN fcy_amount IS NULL THEN AC_CCY END) AS to_ac_ccy
     , MAX(FCY_AMOUNT) AS fcy_amount
     , MAX(EXCH_RATE) AS exch_rate
     , MAX(LCY_AMOUNT) AS lcy_amount
     , MAX(RELATED_CUSTOMER) AS related_customer
FROM   ACVW_ALL_AC_ENTRIES
WHERE  TRN_REF_NO = '001INFT233140130'
AND    event = 'INIT';
```